# Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to execute this neural network of 6 inputs and 6 outputs but an exception is thrown

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
```

```
# Entradas
x1 = 0
x2 = 0
x3 = 0
x4 = 0
x5 = 0
x6 = 0

# Salidas
y1 = 0
y2 = 0
y3 = 0
y4 = 0
y5 = 0
y6 = 1

# crea el modelo
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=6, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))


# Compila el modelo
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Ajusta el modelo
model.fit([x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6], [y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6], epochs=150, batch_size=10)


# evalua el modelo
scores = model.evaluate([x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6], [y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6])

print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input and output dimensions should be:

```
(number_of_data_input,input_dimension) 
(number_of_data_output,output_dimension)
```

Since you have 1 input and 1 output both 6 dimension . So you should pass `(1,6)` dimensions in fit and evaluate functions not `(6,)`.
So fit function should be:

```
model.fit([[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6]], [[y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6]], epochs=150, batch_size=10)
```

And evaluate function should be:

```
scores = model.evaluate([[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6]], [[y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6]])
```